# Proguard debug version of app doesn't include method parameters or variables

Tags: android, proguard

So I have an app which uses a couple of very large SDKs (such as the Amazon AWS SDK). In order to circumvent the 64k method limit on the dex file, I run proguard on both prod and debug builds of the app for it to successfully compile.

The proguard file is below:

```
-keep class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.** { *; }
-keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.**
```

The app runs fine, and I can use Android Studio's built in debugger in order to add break points and step through the code.

However, when I do this, I've noticed that any method parameters that are normally logged in the Variables section of the debug window are not showing up. Also, any regular variable declared such as

`int number = 4;`

won't show up either. The only variables that do show up are class member variables.

Is there something I need to add to my proguard file in order to get the rest of these variables? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ProGuard's obfuscation step by default removes variable names, since the virtual machine doesn't need them. You can preserve them with

```
-keepattributes LocalVariableTable, LocalVariableTypeTable
```

For debugging, you can probably just apply shrinking, disabling optimization (time-consuming) and obfuscation (difficult to debug):

```
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
```